# How to format a partition inside of an img file?

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk-image

I created an `img` file via the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=2M count=200 > binary.img
```

It's just a file with zeroes, but I can use it in `fdisk` and create a partition table:

```
# fdisk binary.img

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x51707f21.

Command (m for help): p
Disk binary.img: 400 MiB, 419430400 bytes, 819200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x51707f21
```

and, let's say, one partition:

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-819199, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-819199, default 819199): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 399 MiB.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

When I check the partition table, I get the following result:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk binary.img: 400 MiB, 419430400 bytes, 819200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7f3a8a6a

Device      Boot Start    End Sectors  Size Id Type
binary.img1       2048 819199  817152  399M 83 Linux
```

So the partition exists. When I try to format this partition via gparted, I get the following error:

[image]

I don't know why it looks for `binary.img1` , and I have no idea how to format the partition from command live.

Does anyone know how to  format it using ext4 filesystem?

Comment: One option is to do the losetup trick from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/69447) and then run mkfs.ext4 against the loopback device.

Comment: I've found this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87189/52763 . And this is actually what I wanted. The problem is, when I check the device in gparted, I get `Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.` . Here's the pic: http://i.imgur.com/dl7XAC4.png .Is this some kind of a bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can access the disk image and its individual partitions via the loopback feature. You have already discovered that some disk utilities will operate (reasonably) happily on disk images. However, `mkfs` is not one of them (but strangely `mount` is).

Here is output from `fdisk -lu binary.img`:

> ```
> Disk binary.img: 400 MiB, 419430400 bytes, 819200 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> ...
>
> Device           Boot Start    End Sectors  Size Id Type
> binary.img1            2048 819199  817152  399M 83 Linux
> ```

To access the partition you've created you have a couple of choices

1. The explicit route

   ```
   losetup --offset $((512*2048)) --sizelimit $((512*817152)) --show --find binary.img
   /dev/loop0
   ```

   The output `/dev/loop0` is the name of the loop device that has been allocated. The `--offset` parameter is just the partition's offset (`Start`) multiplied by the sector size (`512`). Whereas `--sizelimit` is the size of the partition, and you can calculate it in the following way: End-Start+1, which is 819199-2048+1=817152 , and that number also has to be multiplied by the sector size.

   You can then use `/dev/loop0` as your reference to the partition:

   ```
   mkfs -t ext4 -L img1 /dev/loop0
   mkdir -p /mnt/img1
   mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/img1
   ...
   umount /mnt/img1
   losetup -d /dev/loop0
   ```
2. The implicit route

   ```
   losetup --partscan --show --find binary.img
   /dev/loop0
   ```

   The output `/dev/loop0` is the name of the primary loop device that has been allocated. In addition, the `--partscan` option tells the kernel to scan the device for a partition table and assign subsidiary loop devices automatically. In your case with the one partition you also get `/dev/loop0p1`, which you can then use as your reference to the partition:

   ```
   mkfs -t ext4 -L img1 /dev/loop0p1
   mkdir -p /mnt/img1
   mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/img1
   ...
   umount /mnt/img1
   losetup -d /dev/loop0
   ```

Comment: @Mikhail curious to see you calculated the partition size when it was already given as part of the `fdisk` output.

Comment: What's wrong with some maths? Besides, it's good to know that you can easily get the right sector number in that way, just in case...

Comment: Just a quick observation: "mkfs frontend is deprecated in favour of filesystem specific mkfs.<type> utils", quoted from mkfs man-pages.

Comment: @gmagno that's correct now, certainly. But as far as I can determine without digging for too long or too hard, that notice was only first released with util-linux 2.25-rc1, and that didn't get in to Debian stable until quite some time after June 2015. Feel free to update the answer with current information though.

Answer (score 16):

There is another way to do this in general, use `kpartx` (**not** kde related)

```
sudo kpartx -a binary.img
```

and now you should have  all partition devices defined under `/dev/mapper` as **loop0p1**, **loop0p2**, ...

and then

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/loop0p1
```

Optionnaly, when you are done, you can run also

```
sudo kpartx -d binary.img
```

to get rid of the loop0p? deivce

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't have more votes. IMO it's the best answer...!

Comment: Works with GPT partitions, e.g., if you want to modify the EFI partition off of a whole-disk dd.

Comment: +1, because this approach spares you a lot of headaches and is very easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know why it looks for `binary.img1`

(… and later for `binary.img2` buried in the commentary.)

That is because the tools are expecting the filenames to follow a specific pattern.  That pattern is the one used by device files for actual discs and disc volumes on your system, namely:

- A device file encompassing the whole disc is named `sda` (or something else).  This is what `fdisk` expects to make use of.
- Device files for individual slices of the disc, described by its partitioning, are named `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda3`, and so forth.  This is what tools such as `gparted` expect to make use of when they tell `mkfs` to do things on *individual disc volumes*.

Of course, ordinary files don't overlap in the manner that disc devices files do.  The discussions involving the loopback filesystem that you have seen are all about taking a single whole-disc image file and using loopback to create the `1`, `2`, `3`, and so forth files that reflect the individual slices within it, once the desired partition layout has been written to the partition table.

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal runnable `sfdisk` + `mke2fs` example without `sudo`**

In this example, we will create, without `sudo` or `setsuid`, an image file that contains two ext2 partitions, each populated with files from a host directory.

We will then use `sudo losetup` just to mount the partitions to test that the Linux kernel can actually read them as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/how-to-mount-one-partition-from-an-image-file-that-contains-multiple-partitions/39675265#39675265

For more details, see:

- `sfdisk`: deals with the partition table: https://superuser.com/questions/332252/how-to-create-and-format-a-partition-using-a-bash-script/1132834#1132834
- `mke2fs`: deals with EXT formatting of partitions: https://superuser.com/questions/605196/how-to-create-ext2-image-without-superuser-rights/1366762#1366762

The example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Input params.
root_dir_1=root1
root_dir_2=root2
partition_file_1=part1.ext2
partition_file_2=part2.ext2
partition_size_1_megs=32
partition_size_2_megs=32
img_file=img.img
block_size=512

# Calculated params.
mega="$(echo '2^20' | bc)"
partition_size_1=$(($partition_size_1_megs * $mega))
partition_size_2=$(($partition_size_2_megs * $mega))

# Create a test directory to convert to ext2.
mkdir -p "$root_dir_1"
echo content-1 > "${root_dir_1}/file-1"
mkdir -p "$root_dir_2"
echo content-2 > "${root_dir_2}/file-2"

# Create the 2 raw ext2 images.
rm -f "$partition_file_1"
mke2fs \
  -d "$root_dir_1" \
  -r 1 \
  -N 0 \
  -m 5 \
  -L '' \
  -O ^64bit \
  "$partition_file_1" \
  "${partition_size_1_megs}M" \
;
rm -f "$partition_file_2"
mke2fs \
  -d "$root_dir_2" \
  -r 1 \
  -N 0 \
  -m 5 \
  -L '' \
  -O ^64bit \
  "$partition_file_2" \
  "${partition_size_2_megs}M" \
;

# Default offset according to
part_table_offset=$((2**20))
cur_offset=0
bs=1024
dd if=/dev/zero of="$img_file" bs="$bs" count=$((($part_table_offset + $partition_size_1 + $partition_size_2)/$bs)) skip="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
printf "
type=83, size=$(($partition_size_1/$block_size))
type=83, size=$(($partition_size_2/$block_size))
" | sfdisk "$img_file"
cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $part_table_offset))
# TODO: can we prevent this and use mke2fs directly on the image at an offset?
# Tried -E offset= but could not get it to work.
dd if="$partition_file_1" of="$img_file" bs="$bs" seek="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $partition_size_1))
rm "$partition_file_1"
dd if="$partition_file_2" of="$img_file" bs="$bs" seek="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $partition_size_2))
rm "$partition_file_2"

# Test the ext2 by mounting it with sudo.
# sudo is only used for testing, the image is completely ready at this point.

# losetup automation functions from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/how-to-mount-one-partition-from-an-image-file-that-contains-multiple-partitions/39675265#39675265
loop-mount-partitions() (
  set -e
  img="$1"
  dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P "$img")"
  echo "$dev" | sed -E 's/.*[^[:digit:]]([[:digit:]]+$)/\1/g'
  for part in "${dev}p"*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      # Single partition image.
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    echo "$dst" 1>&2
    sudo mkdir -p "$dst"
    sudo mount "$part" "$dst"
  done
)
loop-unmount-partitions() (
  set -e
  for loop_id in "$@"; do
    dev="/dev/loop${loop_id}"
    for part in "${dev}p"*; do
      if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
        part="${dev}"
      fi
      dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
      sudo umount "$dst"
    done
    sudo losetup -d "$dev"
  done
)

loop_id="$(loop-mount-partitions "$img_file")"
sudo cmp /mnt/loop0p1/file-1 "${root_dir_1}/file-1"
sudo cmp /mnt/loop0p2/file-2 "${root_dir_2}/file-2"
loop-unmount-partitions "$loop_id"
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/77dd7baa68dac3534a50f8a084f732f378113c59/mke2fs-multi.sh).

**Helper to wrap an existing raw filesystem file into an image**

Extracted from the above, the following can be useful:

```
# Put a raw filesystem file into a disk image with a partition table.
#
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209566/how-to-format-a-partition-inside-of-an-img-file/527132#527132
#
# Usage:
#
#     sfdisk-fs-to-img root.ext2
#
# Creates a file:
#
#     sfdisk-fs-to-img root.ext2.img
#
sfdisk-fs-to-img() (
  partition_file_1="$1"
  img_file="${partition_file_1}.img"
  block_size=512
  partition_size_1="$(wc -c "$partition_file_1" | awk '{print $1}')"
  part_table_offset=$((2**20))
  cur_offset=0
  bs=1024
  dd if=/dev/zero of="$img_file" bs="$bs" count=$((($part_table_offset + $partition_size_1)/$bs)) skip="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
  printf "
  type=83, size=$(($partition_size_1/$block_size))
  " | sfdisk "$img_file"
  cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $part_table_offset))
  dd if="$partition_file_1" of="$img_file" bs="$bs" seek="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
  cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $partition_size_1))
)
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/dotfiles/blob/19bac69225777aa2507dcfb4eab51e9c114a025b/home/.bashrc#L2693).

Answer (score 0):

Though this topic is not directly related, it mentions a lot of the same and related information.

[Debian wiki | Raspberry Pi and qemu-user-static](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi/qemu-user-static)

If you cannot use `apt` to install some of the commands mentioned in this post, try using `apt-cache search [package_name]`. This may not turn up any results if the command comes from a package of a different name.

For instance, `losetup` could formerly be installed as `losetup` using `apt install losetup`, but it is now part of `util-linux` in Ubuntu's repository. The way you find out what package acts as a container for another package, you must use the search for the online repository for you Linux distribution. Or, if you must install it from another source, use a Web search engine.

Some packages worth checking out...

`util-linux genisoimage dosfstools squashfs-tools fsarchiver xfsprogs reiserfsprogs reiser4progs jfsutils ntfsprogs btrfs-tools`

Every Linux distribution also has its own online manpages. Sometimes it is easier to use the manpages than a tutorial. The manual pages will also tell you all the command options and parameters. A tutorial usually will only focus on the ones used.